# FatalErrorException: Call to a member function count() on a non-object

Tags: php, database, random, laravel-5, unique

I'm trying to generate a unique/random string in Laravel 5 and check it through my table to see if it exists.

This is what I have, but it seems to be giving the error stated in the title:

```
    public static function generate()
    {
        $exists = true;
        while ($exists) {
            $code = str_random(15);
            $check = self::where('code', $code)->first();
            if( ! $check->count()){
                $exists = false;
            }
        }
        return $code;
    }
```

Anyone know why it's giving this error?

Comment: The error is saying it's not returning an object for the count method to be called on. If you run `self::where('code', $code)->first()` you'll see most likely there's nothing there. Try `if(!$check)` instead of calling the count method on it.

Comment: Great, I'll throw up an answer if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're seeing is telling you that you're trying to call a method on a value which is not an object. Most likely in your code you're returning null as the where in your query didn't return anything results. You can always see what you're returning in Laravel queries by using `dd()`:

`dd(Self::where('code', $code)->first())`

So before calling `count()` or any other method on a value for which you're expecting an object you should check it's not null.

Do to this you can update your if statement in the code you provided:

```
public static function generate()
{
    $exists = true;

    while ($exists)
    {
        $code = str_random(15);

        // It's good practice to capitalise objects: Self instead of self
        $check = Self::where('code', $code)->first();

        if(!$check )
        {
            $exists = false;
        }
    }

    return $code;
}
```

As mentioned by Halayem Anis you can also test if the value you're checking is an object using the `is_object()` function, but I think you may need to use the `&&` operator instead of `||`:

```
if(!$check && !is_object($check))
```

Comment: 1k closer ... :) keep going

Comment: Haha thanks a lot my friend hope to join the 1k club soon :) - btw I'm completely unsure if you need to use `&&` or `||` would be grateful if you can clarify that

Answer (score 2):

Always check your returned value before processing ...

```
public static function generate()
        {
            $exists = true;
            while ($exists) {
                $code = str_random(15);
                $check = self::where('code', $code)->first();
                if( is_null ($check) ||
                    ! is_object($check) ||
                    ! $check->count())
                {
                    $exists = false;
                }
            }
            return $code;
        }
```